# Can thanking God lead to misfortune?

Tags: thanksgiving

In commenting on Gen. 30:38, [Rabbenu Bahya](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.30.38?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en) says:

> Do not question how it is possible that the power of the evil eye is so great that it can even interfere with miracles! We find that the birth of Yaakov’s children was influenced by the power of the evil eye. Leah had made a single comment in that she thanked the Lord for allowing her to have born a fourth son, i.e. more than the three sons out of twelve which she could expect to bear by right, and as a result of this comment she became subject to the power of the evil eye. Immediately after she had made this comment we read ותעמוד מלדת “she stopped giving birth.” The mere fact that she had said herself that she had received more than she was entitled to exposed her to the envy of others.

So Leah “became subject to the power of the evil eye” because the Torah says she thanked God for having allowed her to bear a fourth son, and immediately after that it says “she stopped giving birth.” [Genesis 29:35]

How can thanking God for blessings received become, *ipso facto*, the reason for future misfortune?  Is the lesson here that thanks to God should be given quietly, out of everybody's earshot (if indeed Leah said it within somebody's earshot)?  Is this covered anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't for thanking Hashem per se but rather the way she expressed it. Based on the context of the Rabbunu Bachya the issue was that she allowed other to know how she felt and caused the Aiyn Hora.

שכן מצינו בלידת השבטים שבשביל דבור אחד של לאה שאמרה אודה את ה' שנתנה הודאה בבן רביעי על שהכירה שנטלה
יותר מחלקה שלט בה עין הרע

On the topic of Aiyan Hora the Mictav M'Eliyhu says that it only works when you make other people  aware of  your good fortune which to some degree Leah was doing by naming him Yehuda for that reason.

Also the Mogen Avrohom says that a person should  never say that "I have received more than I deserve"  because that is also questioning the fairness of Hashem's judgment. (There are other way the sentiment can be expressed without saying it, like "I thank Hashem for the tremendous amount of Brocha he has given in my life. I do not know why he saw fit to give it to me" etc)

Leah calling him Yehuda because she received more than her portion was saying she received more than she deserved and causing scrutiny.

Sorry I don't have the exact  mekoros offhand. I  just remember seeing them in the past . I don't know enough about this topic for this answer to be in any way definitive on this question .